# How to install Realtek Driver RTL8187 on Ubuntu Lucid without internet

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, ubuntu-10.04, network-adapter

How do you install the Realtek RTL8187 WLAN driver when the Ubuntu machine has no Internet connection?  I've looked this up but all of the tutorials I've found usually had an `apt-get install` command in them so they will not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the package from another machine that has an internet connection. Also, download any possible dependencies. You can download the packages directly using a web-browser from packages.ubuntu.com and then you can install them manually using

`dpkg -i package.deb`

That should do.